# Download file from archive.org

Tags: php, download, archive

I would like to download a file from archive.org, the target is correct, but it give a file as 0KB as below, using the same script, and downloading the same file from my own server, it goes TRUE, and the file is downloaded.

[image: 0KB]

Here is the script, link to hint:

```
$saveit = '<a href="Files/direct_download.php?path='.$directLink.'/&file='.$fileName.'" id="'.$id.'" style="cursor: pointer;" target="_BLANK">';
$saveit .='<img src="'.$path2icons.'Download32_32.png" class="embedDownload masterTooltip" width="25" height="25"  title="حفظ الملف" align="absmiddle" />';
$saveit .='</a>';
echo $saveit;
```

direct_download.php:

```
$url = $_GET['path'];

//echo $url.'<br>';

$fileName = $_GET['file'];

//echo $fileName;

set_time_limit(0);

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: application/download"); 
header("Content-Disposition: filename=$fileName");

$ch = curl_init($url.$fileName);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);        
exit();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. Try add user agent:

`curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "My User Agent" );`

2. Try download file by wget.

`system("wget ....")`

Comment: How can I know the user agent, and the function system is disabled from the server

Comment: For example, You may use user User Agent from $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']